# Using middleman, how do you include one HAML file in another HAML file?

Tags: ruby, layout, haml, middleman

I'm using middleman to do some rapid prototyping and can't for the life of me figure out how to include one HAML file into another HAML file.

I can include stuff in a layout file, but can't get one non-layout file to include another non-layout file.  There are blocks of HTML that I want to reuse on some pages and I  think I could do this. I've tried:

```
- render: partial=>"shared/nav.haml"
=shared/nav.html
="shared/nav.html
```

and none of these work.

Am I missing a config option or plugin?  This is a fresh middleman install.

---

### **ANSWER**

Partials *may* need file names that start with an underscore.  My partial is placed in a folder called shared.  The full name of the file is _nav.html.haml

This worked for me.

```
!= haml :"shared/_nav"
```

Example in context:

```
#email.main.subscriber.resize
  #bg-wrap
    %div
      %img{:src=>"images/backgrounds/image.png",:alt=>""}
  %section#zone10
    != haml :"shared/_nav"
```

You may also use the format specified in the approved answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been using HAML with MiddleMan and couldn't be happier.  Here is what is working for me:

I have a file: `source/_donate_buttons.h`

```
 #DonationButtons
   %p= t('searching.donate_cover_costs')
   %br
   = partial(:paypal_donate_button, :locals => {:amount => 1, 
     :amount_text => t('searching.donate_1')})
```

This uses the partial statement shown to include a file called `source/_paypal_donate_button.html.haml`.

And I include the `_donate_buttons.html.haml` file itself in a couple of places with:

```
= partial "donate_buttons"
```

though I think this could also be:

```
= partial :donate_buttons
```

I.e. I think `partial` is the magic you're looking for.

And, just for completeness, here is a slightly stripped down `_paypal_donate_button.haml` which shows how the paramaterization works there:

```
-btnclass = (locals.key?(:highlight) && locals[:highlight] ? "HighlightedDonationButton" : "DonationButton")
-btnstyle = locals.key?(:button_style) && locals[:button_style]
.DonationButtonContainer
  %form{:action => "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", :method => "post"}
    %input{:name => "business", :type => "hidden", :value => "payments@example.com"}
    %input{:name => "cmd", :type => "hidden", :value => "_donations"}
    %input{:name => "amount", :type => "hidden", :value => "#{amount}.00"}
    %input{:name => "currency_code", :type => "hidden", :value => "USD"}
    %input{:class => btnclass, :alt => t('paypal.alt_text'),
      :style => "cursor: pointer; font-size: 18px; #{btnstyle}", :type => "submit", :value => amount_text}
```

Fwiw, I don't think the file needs to be `_filename.html.haml` and can instead be `_filename.haml`. Also, I'm localizing these, so ignore the t('tagname') and just put strings there. *(I didn't want to introduce an error copy-pasting the examples so I left them in there.)*

Hope this helps!